# Batch file - Closing separate cmd windows opened by a batch file process

Tags: windows, batch-file, selenium, cmd

I am putting together a batch file which does the following:

1. Start Selenium test hub
2. Start Selenium test node
3. Run Selenium test script
4. Open test result xml doc.
5. Close Selenium hub and node

The Selenium hub and node are opened by calling 2 batch files using the START command so they open in their own cmd windows.  I am all good with my process up to point 5), closing the two cmd windows containing the hub and node.

I know you can close all "cmd.exe" processes but that seems way to much of a blunt instrument.  Is there a way of identifying or keeping a handle on the hub and node cmd windows opened by my batch script so that I can then just close those two only?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to the wonderful npocmaka answer, if you know or can set the title of the started Selenium windows, can use this information to retrieve and filter the list of tasks with those titles.

When output to console is correct, remove the `echo` command from taskkill line

```
@echo off

    rem Prepare environment
    setlocal enableextensions

    rem Configure list of window titles
    set titles="seleniumHUB" "seleniumNODE"

    rem For each title in title list
    for %%t in (%titles%) do (

        rem Get the list of task with the indicated window title. 
        rem The list is get from tasklist, in verbose mode and in csv format 
        rem The last column in the list is the window title 
        for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a in (
            'tasklist /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe" /v /fo csv ^| findstr /i /r /c:"%%~t[^,]*$"'
        ) do (
            echo taskkill /pid %%~b
        )
    )

    rem Clean
    endlocal
```

Comment: aaw yes.`Title`.Simple and neat.+1

Comment: This works perfectly for me and gets around the problem I mention in the comment I made for npocmaka's solution above which, initially, seemed to achieve what I wanted.  Promoted your answer MC to the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=2 delims=;= " %%a in ('wmic process call create "cmd.exe /c C:\selenium.bat"^,"c:\workdir" ^| find "ProcessId"') do (
    set "cmd_pid=%%a"
)

taskkill /PID %cmd_pid% /f
```

with `wmic process call create "cmd.exe /c C:\selenium.bat"` you can start a process and get its PID and when you to kill it you can use `taskkill /PID %cmd_pid% /f`

Comment: Thanks very much!  I'm something of a noob at batch scripting so still working through the different elements of this but what I have figured out so far works very nicely.

Comment: you can use `PSlist -t` to detect subprocesses , but you need to download it from sysinternals.Later I'll make a script.

Comment: Actually, after testing a bit further, this idea unfortunately leaves a conhost.exe and associated selenium javaw.exe process active for each of the selenium cmd windows although the cdm.exe processes have been killed.